# (Groovy | 12.04 | armv7l) Can't run 'roscore' nor 'roslaunch'

Tags: ubuntu, rosgraph, ubuntu-precise, roscore, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am installing ROS Groovy (from source) on a Tablet, whose Kernel is armv7l, and am having no luck when running the following command:

```
root@localhost:~# roscore
… logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/---bunch-of-numbers----/roslaunch-localhost-22058.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 265, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 206, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, self.port, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 408, in load_config_default
    config.master.uri = rosgraph.network.create_local_xmlrpc_uri(port)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 281, in create_local_xmlrpc_uri
    return 'http://%s:%s/'%(get_host_name(), port)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 266, in get_hostname
    hostname = get_local_addresses()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 173, in get_local_address
    addrs = get_local_addresses()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 211, in get_local_addresses
    ifaces = ifaddrs.getifaddrs()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/ifaddrs.py", line 147, in getifaddrs
    addr += "%02x:" % si.sll_addr[i]
IndexError: invalid index
```

My Environment is:

```
root@localhost:~# export | grep ROS
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="groovy"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="h t t p://localhost:11311" <-- ROS ANSWERS DOES NOT LET ME PUBLISH LINKS
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/ros_ws:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros"
```

I am connected through VNC and my interface configuration is:

```
root@localhost:~# ifconfig
```

only `lo` and `eth0` appear.

Any suggestions to get `roscore` and `roslaunch` to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54776/(groovy-%7C-12.04-%7C-armv7l)-can%27t-run-%27roscore%27-nor-%27roslaunch%27/) by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-02-10**:
Instead of [SOLVED]'ing you might post the resolution as an answer and mark it as accepted, that's how it works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to a comment from @adamantivm on [github](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/30#issuecomment-11010748)

I did the following and solved the issue:

```
sudo gedit /opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/ifaddrs.py
```

go to line 112 and comment all the `if ifa.ifa_addr:` segment and add the following:

```
if ifa.ifa_addr is None:
     continue
```

This is for VNC connected products.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-12**:
Hi, I am having the same problem and added that if statement to every 'ifaddrs.py' I could find, but this did not resolve my issue. Do you have another suggestion? Did you do anything else? ps. I am compiling on an Odroid (arm).

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-12**:
For now, I commented out the AF_PACKET part in the python script. I don't think I need it ;)

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-12**:
@amrivera can you clarify?